# What is the most efficient way to traverse a hard disk and determine whether a given block is currently in use?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I'm working on a personal project to regularly (monthly-ish) traverse my hard disk and shred (overwrite with zeros) any blocks on the disk not currently allocated to any inode(s).

`C` seemed like the most logical language to do this in given the low-level nature of the project, but I am not sure how best to find the unused blocks in the filesystem. I've found some questions around S.O. and other places that are similar to this, but did not see any consensus on the best way to **efficiently** and **effectively** find these unused blocks.

`df` has come up in any questions even remotely similar to this, but I don't believe it has the resolution necessary to specify exact block offsets unless I am missing something. Is there another utility I should look into or some other direction entirely?

Whatever solution I develop would need to be able to handle, at minimum, `ext3` filesystems, and preferably `ext4` also.

Comment: First of all, you need to decide which filesystem(s) you're going to support.

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say `ext3` and `ext4`. I'll modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Can't you simply create a large enough temporary file and delete it afterwards?

Comment: Not really, @AkiSuihkonen. The goal is to remove records of all files that are "deleted" from the system. Having a big `tmp` directory would mean that all files, including non-deleted ones, would be removed.

Comment: I dont' follow. How would a temporary file occupy anything else than the free space? There are other issues, such that some daemon process (or an application) could terminate with an error and corrupt open files, if there was temporarily no free space on the device.

Comment: You're missing the point. The idea is to fully remove files no longer in use in the system. Your approach would not only fail to fully remove files from the disk (they would just be unlinked, I believe) and would be indiscriminate in removing files. I would lose everything as soon as my machine reboots if I kept my entire filesystem in a tmp directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux currently support over a dozen different filesystems so the answer will depend on which one you choose.

However, they should all have an easy way of finding free blocks otherwise creating new files or extending current files would be a bit slow.

For example, `ext2` has, at the start of each block group, a header containing, among other things, the free list for that block group. I don't believe this has changed in `ext4` even though there's a lot of extra stuff in there.

You would probably be far better traversing the free blocks in those block headers rather than taking an arbitrary block and trying to figure out if it's used or free.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have any general solution to find out which blocks are in use other than writing your own implementation to read and parse the on disk filesystem data which is highly specific to the filesystems you want to support. How the data looks on disk is something that is often undocumented outside of the code for that filesystem and when documented the documentation is often out of date compared to the actual implementation.

Your best bet is to read the implementation of fsck for the filesystem you want to support since it does more or less what you're interested in, but be warned that many fsck implementations out there don't always check all of the data that belongs to the filesystem. You might have alternate superblocks and certain metadata that fsck doesn't check (or only checks in case the primary superblock is corrupted).

If you really want to do what you say you want to do and not just learn about filesystems your best bet is to dump your filesystem like a normal backup, wipe the disk and restore the backup. I highly doubt anything else is safe to do especially considering that your disk wiping application might break your filesystem with any kernel update you do.